# switch variable and write problems,python

Tags: python, output

```
import csv
import sys 
def switch():
    file1=open('enjoysport.csv','r')
    for line in file1:
        line.split(",")[0],line.split(",")[-1]=line.split(",")[-1],line.split(",")[0]
    file1.close()                                       
    origin=sys.stdout
    fil2=open("test.csv","w")
    sys.stdout=fil2
    print(file1)
    sys.stdout = origin                  
    fil2.close()
switch()
```

I want to switch the first column and last column ,but it didn't work,what's more,the file after switching cannot be written into the new csv.file?

like this:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='agaricus_lepiota.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

what's wrong?Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually write the updated row to the file, you can also use the *csv* lib to read and write your file content:

```
def switch():
    with open('enjoysport.csv') as f,  open("test.csv", "w") as out:
        wr = csv.writer(out)
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            row[0], row[-1] = row[-1], row[0]
            wr.writerow(row) # actually write it to test.csv
```

In your own code all you are doing is shifting elements in each row, you never write the result so it is a pointless exercise.

Why you see `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='agaricus_lepiota.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>` is because `sys.stdout = fil2` *redirects stdout* to *file2*, then you print the reference to the `file1` i.e the file object so that gets written/redirected to your file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line

```
    line.split(",")[0],line.split(",")[-1]=line.split(",")[-1],line.split(",")[0]
```

You create four temporary lists by split, which are discarded after that line directly because they are not assigned to any variable.

You have to process one line and write it directly to the new file:

```
file1=open('enjoysport.csv','r')
fil2=open("test.csv","w")
for line in file1:
    parts = line.rstrip().split(',')
    parts[0],parts[-1] = parts[-1], parts[0]
    file2.write(','.join(parts) + '\n')
file1.close()
file2.close()
```